# Jasmine Open And Close Db Connections

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, gulp-jasmine

I have multiple files with unit tests. I want to avoid to concat them. I need to close the mongoose connection in order for `gulp-jasmine` to [exit](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-jasmine/issues/49). I also want to avoid to put the connection handling into an `it` block, because it wouldn't belong there.

If I move my connect/disconnect function into `beforeAll` and `afterAll` e.g.

## Code

### Unit Tests

```
describe "a unit test"
  beforeAll (done)->
    db = testSettings.connectDB (err)->
      throw err if err?
      done()

  ...

  afterAll (done)->
    testSettings.disconnectDB (err)->
      throw err if err?
      done()
```

Then Jasmine executes the next describes `beforeAll` before `afterAll` could disconnect the db properly.

(Jasmine Docs)[http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown]

> However, be careful using beforeAll and afterAll! Since they are not
>   reset between specs, it is easy to accidentally leak state between
>   your specs so that they erroneously pass or fail.

### Connection Function

```
connections = 0

exports.connectDB = (callback) ->
  configDB = require(applicationDir + 'backend/config/database.js')(environment)

  if connections == 0
    mongoose.connect configDB.url,{auth:{authdb:configDB.authdb}}, (err)->
      if (err)
        console.log(err)
        return callback err

    db = mongoose.connection
    db.on 'error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:')

    db.once 'open', () ->
      connections++
      return callback null, db
      #console.log "Database established"
      #Delete all data and seed new data

  else
    db = mongoose.connection
    return callback null, db

exports.disconnectDB = (callback) ->
  mongoose.disconnect (err)->
    return callback err if err?
    connections--
    return callback()
```

#### EDIT:

Listening for disconnect event does not work either:
exports.disconnectDB = (callback) ->
  console.log "DISCONNECTING FROM DB", mongoose.connection.readyState
  mongoose.disconnect (err)->
    return callback err if err?
    connections--
    console.log "SHOULD BE DISCONNETCED", mongoose.connection.readyState #is not because state is 3 0> disconnecting
    return callback()

mongoose.connection 'disconnected', () ->
    console.log "DIS", mongoose.connection.readyState
    return callback()

## Error

`{ Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.`

## Question

How to properly open & close my connections with `gulp-jasmine`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, still wondering why I can't use the `disconnected` event:

```
connections = 0
disConnectionRetries = 0
MAX_DISCONNECTION_RETRIES = 10

connectDB = (callback) ->
  console.log "CONNECTING TO DB", mongoose.connection.connectionState
  configDB = require(applicationDir + 'backend/config/database.js')(environment)

  if connections == 0
    mongoose.connect configDB.url,{auth:{authdb:configDB.authdb}}, (err)->
      if (err)
        console.log(err)
        return callback err

    db = mongoose.connection
    db.on 'error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:')

    db.once 'open', () ->
      connectionRetries = 0
      connections++
      return callback null, db
      #console.log "Database established"
      #Delete all data and seed new data

  else
    db = mongoose.connection
    return callback null, db

exports.disconnectDB = (callback) ->
  console.log "DISCONNECTING FROM DB", mongoose.connection.readyState
  mongoose.disconnect (err)->
    return callback err if err?
    connections--
    isDisconnected(callback)

isDisconnected = (callback)->
  console.log "SHOULD BE DISCONNETCED", mongoose.connection.readyState
  throw new Error "Cannot disconnect more than #{MAX_DISCONNECTION_RETRIES} retries" if disConnectionRetries > MAX_DISCONNECTION_RETRIES
  if mongoose.connection.readyState == 0
    disConnectionRetries = 0
    return callback()
  else
    disConnectionRetries++
    return setTimeout ()->
      isDisconnected(callback)
    , 50
```